# Sending data I receive with vuejs to python server with flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a project in hand. I used **vuejs** on the frontend. The **API** is written with **php**. I have a **linux** server and i will get it on **python** server. My data needs to be linked between **2 servers**.
Example: **It will run the frontend part running on my Linux server. The file added from the select file section will go to the python server. After the file I sent is processed, it should return it to me as an array (to the frontend on my linux server). I will process the returned data with JSON and save it to MySql. (I don't know how to proceed. Some engineers told me to do it using Flask, but I couldn't find the necessary documentation.**`

```
import imghdr
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 1024 * 1024
app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS'] = ['.pdf']
app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'] = 'uploads'

def validate_image(stream):
    header = stream.read(512)
    stream.seek(0) 
    format = imghdr.what(None, header)
    if not format:
        return None
    return '.' + (format if format != 'pdf' else 'pdf')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_files():
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)
    if filename != '':
        file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        if file_ext not in app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS'] or \
                file_ext != validate_image(uploaded_file.stream):
            abort(400)
        uploaded_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], filename))
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

I want to use a structure similar to this, but I will only send **pdf** as a parameter and I want all transactions to be on the same page.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem? Do you get error message when you run Flask in console/terminal?

Comment: all documentation is on Flask page. Did you read it? There should be also tutorials for Flask - like [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

Comment: maybe start with empty code to check if it works and later learn how to get data. If you send file using `form` then you can get it as `request.files`. And if you want send back JSON data then you can use `return jsonify(data)` instead of `return render_template()`

Comment: I learned the logic of sending parameters. My real problem is to send file from frontend to my .py file on my python server using flask with vuejs

Comment: The parameter I sent should be returned to me as an array after being processed in my .py file

Comment: I think you might have a three-fold problem: 1) Send file to Flask (assuming a POST request). 2) Send file via JavaScript (perform POST request with JS via jQuery, axios ...) 3) Send file via vuejs component. And we still did not talk about the connection between your two servers and the frontend. Therefore, your questions seems to need a bit more focus.

Comment: Yes, it is very difficult to explain because the project is very complex. Sorry for my explanation. I will try to explain with a short logic. @albert

Comment: vuejs(to start the request with button) -> flask api(normally I use php api, I should use flask because I will request to python server) -> file(file with pdf extension)->.py file (python server)->response ->vuejs-> users   @albert

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you get in Flask. I don't know if vuejs send it as `form` data or JSON data. And you should run all in `upload_files` - get file, process it, generate array, and use `return` to send it back. But I also don't know if `vuejs` need it as normal text, HTML or JSON data. So first try to use simpler code and `print()` (and similar function in `vuejs`) to see what you get on both sides - text, HTML, JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Data is sent in 'JSON' format. But I don't know how to merge this with my 'Vuejs' folder. And the user won't get it as a form. Only select file screen will open and user will select file @furas

Comment: I don't know `vuejs` but first I wuold use `print()` in `upload_files` to check what I get in `print( request.args )`, `print( request.form )`, `print( request.files )`, `print( request.json )`. If `vuejs` sends file in `request.files` then you may need to modify current code. If it sends in `request.json` then probably it will need to decode `base64`. And I would also use `return jsonify(data)` to send example data to `vuejs` and check how it get it.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I found a working structure and edited it. You can reach it at [link](https://github.com/korayaslaan/python-flask) . My only problem right now is the welcome process on the python server @furalar